# Format input field value as a currency when user types

Tags: angular, directive

I have below requirement for a text field. When user starts entering his input it should get formatted like below

```
0.00 (Start)
0.01
0.12
1.23
12.34
123.45
1,234.56
12,345.67
123,456.78
```

I use below currency mask which works fine, but i am not able to make the field as empty i.e. user cannot empty the text box. The directive makes the value as 0.0 by default. Can i override the directive, so that user can leave the box empty also? or any other directive for doing the same thing? I am using Angular 4 project

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should help, I tested also on plunker with latest ng2-currency-mask@4.2.0 and all seems to work well.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appZero]'
})
export class AppZeroDirective {

    private _restStage: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private _model: NgModel,
        private _elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {

        this._model.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value: any) => {
            if ((value === null || value === 0) && !this._restStage) {
                this._restStage = true;
                this._elementRef.nativeElement.value = null;
                this._model.control.setValue(null);
                return;
            }
            this._restStage = false;
        });

    }
}
```

Apply [appZero] directive to your input like this:

```
<input appZero currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value">
```

Comment: If you can share the plunker it would be helpful

Comment: I implemented in my code and i see that display value has changed but model value is still 0 when i try to take the model value. Any way i can make that also null or ''. Because i need to show error message to user when text box is empty.

Comment: this._elementRef.nativeElement.value = null; this changes visual value, but you can use this._model to set model value, check the documentation, the idea is that is possible but you should play a little with this.

Comment: I tried to setvalue on _model. Looks like it went into infinite loop as we are subscribing on _model.

Comment: Try to set a flag inside this directive, because you are subscribed to valueChanges this will make loop, and check the flag if this is internal update or external model update, there is no right implementation, you should search one that fits you

Comment: If you update model from directive then set flag to "true" and on next subscription call, you check if this is true then you skip the check or change of new model once again

Comment: I wrote code like below, but still i get stacktrace error when page loads
export class AppZeroDirective {
  constructor(
    private _model: NgModel,
    private _elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
    this._model.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value: any) => {
      let _valueChanged = false;
      if (!value) {
        if(!_valueChanged){
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.value = null;
            this._model.control.setValue(null);
            _valueChanged = true;
        } else {
           _valueChanged = false;
        }
 
      }
    });
  }
 
}

Comment: Sure will wait for your update. I tried a lot in different ways, but could not get rid of that error.

Comment: When i key press any alphabets also it throws out value as 0. Can in prevent it throwing any value when user types in any characters apart from numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
selector: '[appZero]'
})
export class AppZeroDirective {

private _restStage: boolean = false;

constructor(
    private _model: NgModel,
    private _elementRef: ElementRef
) {

    this._model.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value: any) => {
      //  if ((value === null || value === 0) && !this._restStage || (value === '' && this._elementRef.nativeElement.value==='$0')) {
        if ((value === '' && this._elementRef.nativeElement.value==='$0') && !this._restStage) {
            this._restStage = true;
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.value = null;
            this._model.control.setValue(null);
            return;
        }
        this._restStage = false;
    });

   }
}
```